# Excel Macro to paste ROTATED pictures in Cell comments

Tags: excel, vba

This Excel macro is to paste pictures in Excel cell comments. It is working fine. Now, I need a change in it. Pictures should be rotated 270 degree & then pasted in cell comments. When I tried `.Comment.Shape.Rotation = 270` it failed and sent run time error '70'  "Permission Denied". ". I think picture should be pasted & ROTATED at some temporary location or in memory and then called back & pasted in cell comment. 
I have +600 picture and their manual rotation is big task in very limited time. Please help in this matter. Thanks

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set RNG = Range("A2:A600")
    End With
    For Each rCell In RNG
        If Dir$(strPath & "\" & cll.Value & ".jpg") <> "" Then
            With cll
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment ("")
                .Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (strPath & "\" & cll.Value & ".jpg")
                .Comment.Shape.Height = 160
                .Comment.Shape.Width = 120
        '.Comment.Shape.Rotation = 270   'Got Error Message "Permission Denied"
                .Comment.Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                End With
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not vba solution, but could be helpful.
Use [Infranview](http://www.irfanview.com/). This application can rotate all pictures in folder by one click. 
File-> Batch Conversion/Rename...